# Managing high/low priority threads in .net

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, interlocked-increment

The scenario is as follows:
There are a couple of low priority threads that can be interrupted by high priority threads. Whenever a high priority thread asks the low priority threads to pause, they will go to `Wait` state (if they are not in wait state already). However when a high priority thread signals that the low priority threads can `Resume`, the low priority threads should not resume until all the high priority threads that asked the low priority threads to pause have consented.

To solve this I am keeping a track of `Pause()` calls from the high priority threads to the low priority thread in a counter variable. Whenever the high priority thread asks the low priority thread to `Pause()`, the value of the counter is incremented by 1. If after the increment the counter has a value of `1`, it means the thread was not in `Wait`, so ask it to go in `Wait` state. Otherwise just increment `counter` value. On the contrary when a high priority thread calls `Resume()` we decrement the `counter` value and if after the decrement the value is `0`, it means the low priority threads can `Resume` now.

Here is a simplified implementation of my problem. The comparison operation inside if statements with `Interlocked.XXX` is not correct i.e.

> if (Interlocked.Increment(ref _remain) == 1)

, as the read/modify and comparison operations are not atomic.

What am I missing here? I don't want to use thread priority.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestConcurrency
{

// I borrowed this class from Joe Duffy's blog and modified it
public class LatchCounter
{
 private long _remain;
 private EventWaitHandle m_event;
 private readonly object _lockObject;

public LatchCounter()
{
    _remain = 0;
    m_event = new ManualResetEvent(true);
    _lockObject = new object();
}

public void Check()
{
    if (Interlocked.Read(ref _remain) > 0)
    {
        m_event.WaitOne();
    }
}

public void Increment()
{
    lock(_lockObject)
    {
       if (Interlocked.Increment(ref _remain) == 1)
           m_event.Reset();
    }
}

public void Decrement()
{
    lock(_lockObject)
    {
       // The last thread to signal also sets the event.
       if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref _remain) == 0)
           m_event.Set();
    }
}
}



public class LowPriorityThreads
{
private List<Thread> _threads;
private LatchCounter _latch;
private int _threadCount = 1;

internal LowPriorityThreads(int threadCount)
{
    _threadCount = threadCount;
    _threads = new List<Thread>();
    for (int i = 0; i < _threadCount; i++)
    {
        _threads.Add(new Thread(ThreadProc));
    }

    _latch = new CountdownLatch();
}


public void Start()
{
    foreach (Thread t in _threads)
    {
        t.Start();
    }
}

void ThreadProc()
{
    while (true)
    {
        //Do something
        Thread.Sleep(Rand.Next());
        _latch.Check();
    }
}

internal void Pause()
{
    _latch.Increment();
}

internal void Resume()
{
    _latch.Decrement();
}
}


public class HighPriorityThreads
{
private Thread _thread;
private LowPriorityThreads _lowPriorityThreads;

internal HighPriorityThreads(LowPriorityThreads lowPriorityThreads)
{
    _lowPriorityThreads = lowPriorityThreads;
    _thread = new Thread(RandomlyInterruptLowPriortyThreads);
}

public void Start()
{
    _thread.Start();
}

void RandomlyInterruptLowPriortyThreads()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(Rand.Next());

        _lowPriorityThreads.Pause();

        Thread.Sleep(Rand.Next());
        _lowPriorityThreads.Resume();
    }
}
}

 class Program
 {
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    LowPriorityThreads lowPriorityThreads = new LowPriorityThreads(3);
    HighPriorityThreads highPriorityThreadOne = new HighPriorityThreads(lowPriorityThreads);
    HighPriorityThreads highPriorityThreadTwo = new HighPriorityThreads(lowPriorityThreads);

    lowPriorityThreads.Start();
    highPriorityThreadOne.Start();
    highPriorityThreadTwo.Start();
}
}


class Rand
{
internal static int Next()
{
    // Guid idea has been borrowed from somewhere on StackOverFlow coz I like it
    return new System.Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()).Next() % 30000;
}
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just modify Check to do `m_event.WaitOne()` without anything else?

Comment: Not using Thread.Priority is a drastic mistake.  You'll be debugging deadlock until the cows come home.

Comment: Something smells 'off' about this requirement, but I can't quite put my finger on it at the moment.

Comment: @usr: I may not be waiting for one. If more than one high priority thread is in running state then I have to wait for all the high priority threads to give signal

Comment: "I may not be waiting for one": In that case the event will always be set so no wait would be occurring. That looks correct to me.

Comment: @usr: Its difficult to write the code here so I will just take the example on the following page.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189907(v=vs.100).aspx

Lets assume that I had two or more WorkMethods queued and I want wait until all of them give the signal to proceed.

If that still doesn't clarify, can you please point to a code snippet that will help me understand your point of view.

Comment: @Hans: I can't rely on thread priority as I want the low priority threads to do absolutely nothing if a high priority thread is being executed. If I just leave it on priority then the OS might schedule the low priority thread when a high priority thread is running.
<EDIT>Deleted and re-added this comment as I misspelled Hans' name </Edit>

Comment: is this line `_latch = new CountdownLatch();` in the `LowPriorityThreads` constructor correct? Shouldn't it be `new LatchCounter()`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your requirements hence I won't discuss them here.
As far as the implementation goes, I would introduce a "dispatcher" class that will handle inter-threads interaction and also acts a a factory for "runnable" objects.

The implementation, of course is very rough and open for criticism.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadDispatcher td=new ThreadDispatcher();
        Runner r1 = td.CreateHpThread(d=>OnHpThreadRun(d,1));
        Runner r2 = td.CreateHpThread(d => OnHpThreadRun(d, 2));

        Runner l1 = td.CreateLpThread(d => Console.WriteLine("Running low priority thread 1"));
        Runner l2 = td.CreateLpThread(d => Console.WriteLine("Running low priority thread 2"));
        Runner l3 = td.CreateLpThread(d => Console.WriteLine("Running low priority thread 3"));


        l1.Start();
        l2.Start();
        l3.Start();

        r1.Start();
        r2.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();

        l1.Stop();
        l2.Stop();
        l3.Stop();

        r1.Stop();
        r2.Stop();
    }

    private static void OnHpThreadRun(ThreadDispatcher d,int number)
    {
        Random r=new Random();
        Thread.Sleep(r.Next(100,2000));
        d.CheckedIn();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("*** Starting High Priority Thread {0} ***",number));
        Thread.Sleep(r.Next(100, 2000));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("+++ Finishing High Priority Thread {0} +++", number));
        Thread.Sleep(300);
        d.CheckedOut();           
    }
}

public abstract class Runner
{
    private Thread _thread;
    protected readonly Action<ThreadDispatcher> _action;
    private readonly ThreadDispatcher _dispathcer;
    private long _running;
    readonly ManualResetEvent _stopEvent=new ManualResetEvent(false);
    protected Runner(Action<ThreadDispatcher> action,ThreadDispatcher dispathcer)
    {
        _action = action;
        _dispathcer = dispathcer;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _thread = new Thread(OnThreadStart);
        _running = 1;
        _thread.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _stopEvent.Reset();
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _running, 0);
        _stopEvent.WaitOne(2000);
        _thread = null;
        Console.WriteLine("The thread has been stopped.");

    }
    protected virtual void OnThreadStart()
    {
        while (Interlocked.Read(ref _running)!=0)
        {
            OnStartWork();
            _action.Invoke(_dispathcer);
            OnFinishWork();
        }
        OnFinishWork();
        _stopEvent.Set();
    }

    protected abstract void OnStartWork();
    protected abstract void OnFinishWork();
}

public class ThreadDispatcher
{
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _signal=new ManualResetEvent(true);
    private int _hpCheckedInThreads;
    private readonly object _lockObject = new object();

    public void CheckedIn()
    {
        lock(_lockObject)
        {
            _hpCheckedInThreads++;
            _signal.Reset();
        }
    }
    public void CheckedOut()
    {
        lock(_lockObject)
        {
            if(_hpCheckedInThreads>0)
                _hpCheckedInThreads--;
            if (_hpCheckedInThreads == 0)
                _signal.Set();
        }
    }

    private class HighPriorityThread:Runner 
    {
        public HighPriorityThread(Action<ThreadDispatcher> action, ThreadDispatcher dispatcher) : base(action,dispatcher)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnStartWork()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnFinishWork()
        {
        }
    }
    private class LowPriorityRunner:Runner
    {
        private readonly ThreadDispatcher _dispatcher;
        public LowPriorityRunner(Action<ThreadDispatcher> action, ThreadDispatcher dispatcher)
            : base(action, dispatcher)
        {
            _dispatcher = dispatcher;
        }

        protected override void OnStartWork()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("LP Thread is waiting for a signal.");
            _dispatcher._signal.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("LP Thread got the signal.");
        }

        protected override void OnFinishWork()
        {

        }
    }

    public Runner CreateLpThread(Action<ThreadDispatcher> action)
    {
        return new LowPriorityRunner(action, this);
    }

    public Runner CreateHpThread(Action<ThreadDispatcher> action)
    {
        return new HighPriorityThread(action, this);
    }
}
```

}